# Properly implementing the dot notation with ANTLR4 visitors?

Tags: java, interpreters

I am implementing the dot operator/notation you see in languages (`obj.method();`) with ANTLR4.
Everything is working fine (except one thing), a simple hello world program works:

```
module test;
sfunc main {
    std->println(obj="Hello, World!");
}
```

`->` in this language is the equivalent to `.` in Java and many more languages.
If you look at the grammar: [here](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/mau2/blob/master/Mau/src/org/midnightas/mau/parsing/Mau.g4)
You will notice that the parser rule (`exprIdentifier`, the once that allows using `->`) only supports `IDENTIFIER`s, meaning that the `->` notation only works on objects that have been put into variables.

Meaning:

```
a = 5;
a->test();
```

Would work, but:

```
5->test();
```

Would not.

Changing the `IDENTIFIER`s to `expr`s would also not work because it causes a "mutually left recursive" error and would also look bad:

```
5 + 5->test(); // not a good idea
```

My question is, what do I need to change to solve my problem?

Comment: Nothing to say?

Comment: Probably better fit for Stackoverflow?

Comment: To solve which problem? You said everything was working fine.

Comment: @CandiedOrange So I chocked my writing once, it later says about my problem.

Comment: What? It's been almost a month!

Comment: You have got to be kidding me.